# GDB full memory dump of process

Tags: gdb, coredump

I'm trying to dump the memory of a process on a remote machine. The target machine is some kind of an old Linux, and I'm running `gdbserver 8.3` on it that I've compiled.
 
I'm able to create some handy dumps using `gcore` command, however, these dumps are missing all of the `r-x` and `r--` sections, it contains only writable sections. Can anyone guide me on how to generate a full memory dump including everything, preferably in the same core dump format?
I've already tried both

```
set use-coredump-filter on
set use-coredump-filter off
```

and

```
set dump-excluded-mappings on
set dump-excluded-mappings off
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set the core file filter in `/proc/PID/coredump_filter` per http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html.

E.g.

```sh
echo 0xff > /proc/$(pidof foo)/coredump_filter
gcore $(pidof foo)
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you. I still don't understand why `set use-coredump-filter off` didn't solve it.